# How can I install HTML-Parser-3.64 on Perl 5.6?

Tags: perl, html-parser

I am trying to install HTML-Parser-3.64 and I get following report while running `make test`:

```
ERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /home/Perl/bin/perl -Iblib/arch -Iblib/lib -I/home/Perl/5.6.1-nothread/lib/perl5/5.6.1/sun4.SVR4 -I/home/Perl/5.6.1-nothread/lib/perl5/5.6.1 -e 'use Test::Harness qw(&runtests $verbose); $verbose=0; runtests @ARGV;' t/*.t
t/api_version........ok                                                     
t/argspec-bad........ok                                                     
t/argspec............ok                                                     
t/argspec2...........ok                                                     
t/attr-encoded.......ok                                                     
t/callback...........ok                                                     
t/case-sensitive.....ok                                                     
t/cases..............ok                                                     
t/comment............ok                                                     
t/crashme............ok                                                     
t/declaration........ok                                                     
t/default............ok                                                     
t/document...........ok                                                     
t/dtext..............ok                                                     
t/entities...........ok 1/17                                                
t/entities...........NOK 17#     Failed test (t/entities.t at line 74)      
#          got: 'Attention Homeοωnөrs...1ѕt Tімe Eνөг'
#     expected: 'Attention HomeÎ¿ÏnÓ©rs...1Ñt TÑÐ¼e EÎ½Ó©Ð³'
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 17.
t/entities...........dubious                                                
        Test returned status 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
DIED. FAILED test 17
        Failed 1/17 tests, 94.12% okay
t/entities2..........ok                                                     
t/filter-methods.....ok                                                     
t/filter.............ok                                                     
t/handler-eof........ok                                                     
t/handler............ok                                                     
t/headparser-http....ok                                                     
t/headparser.........ok                                                     
        4/15 skipped: Need Unicode support
t/ignore.............ok                                                     
t/largetags..........ok                                                     
t/linkextor-base.....ok                                                     
t/linkextor-rel......ok                                                     
t/magic..............ok                                                     
t/marked-sect........ok                                                     
t/msie-compat........ok                                                     
t/offset.............ok                                                     
t/options............ok                                                     
t/parsefile..........ok                                                     
t/parser.............ok                                                     
t/plaintext..........ok                                                     
t/pod................skipped
        all skipped: Test::Pod 1.00 required for testing POD
t/process............ok                                                     
t/pullparser.........ok                                                     
t/script.............ok                                                     
t/skipped-text.......ok                                                     
t/stack-realloc......ok                                                     
t/textarea...........ok                                                     
t/threads............skipped
        all skipped: Not configured for threads
t/tokeparser.........ok                                                     
t/uentities..........ok 1/26# Looks like you planned 26 tests but ran 1 extra.
t/uentities..........dubious                                                
        Test returned status 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
DIED. FAILED test 27
        Failed 1/26 tests, 96.15% okay (less 27 skipped tests: -2 okay, -7.69%)
t/unbroken-text......ok                                                     
t/unicode-bom........ok                                                     
        2/2 skipped: This perl does not support Unicode
t/unicode............skipped
        all skipped: This perl does not support Unicode
t/xml-mode...........ok                                                     
Failed Test   Stat Wstat Total Fail  Failed  List of Failed
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
t/entities.t     1   256    17    1   5.88%  17
t/uentities.t    1   256    26    1   3.85%  27
3 tests and 33 subtests skipped.
Failed 2/48 test scripts, 95.83% okay. 0/338 subtests failed, 100.00% okay.
*** Error code 11
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `test_dynamic'
```

I have Perl version 5.6.1. and 3.64 version of Parser on Solaris 8.
I have seen following similar error reported by another person on internet at http://www.cpantesters.org/cpan/report/6653478. But could not see any reply or solution for that.

Comment: I would say it is time to upgrade to `5.8.9`.

Comment: @Silence What in the great green garden up in the sky does this have to do with ServerFault? The test is failing due to lacking Unicode support in 5.6.1.

Comment: Maybe it's not Unicode. Looks like this test expects "Added Latin 1", see http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/GAAS/HTML-Parser-3.64/t/entities.t, in which case it's not a 5.6.1-specific issue.

Comment: Correction: t/uentities.t is about unicode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are comfortable with the other test results, and you don't expect to use `HTML::Parser` for pages which require extended character sets, then you can force an install.

From command-line:

```
 $ perl -MCPAN -e 'force install HTML::Parser'
```

From CPAN command line:

```
cpan> force install HTML::Parser
```

From your build directory (if you'd rather not use `CPAN`):

```
mv t/entities.t t/entities.tt
mv t/uentities.t t/uentities.tt
make install
```

Comment: The `mv`'s are unnecessary, because `make install` doesn't run or install tests.

Answer (score 1):

You need to report it to [HTML::Parser bug tracker](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=HTML-Parser). Cpantesters results are only reports, in many cases automatic, so to gain attention of author you need to use bug tracker.

P.S. Upgrading is also a good idea (in case you have no problems of doing this) - Perl has changed much in 9 years from 5.6.1.